# Hubble's law for approaching, rather than receding, galaxies

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

[Hubble's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law) states that, the [recessional velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recessional_velocity) $v_r$ of a distant object, relative to an observer, is
$$
v_r = H_0D + v_{pec}
$$
where $v_{pec}$ is the peculiar velocity, $H_0$ is the Hubble constant, and $D$ is the distance between the object and the observer.

I'm a bit confused about the case where $v_{pec}<-H_0D$, namely when the object, e.g. the [Andromeda galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_Galaxy), is approaching us despite Hubble's law favoring it to recede from us. As the Andromeda galaxy approaches us, $D$ will decrease, so $v_r$ will become even more negative. Does this mean that cosmic expansion will accelerate the Andromeda galaxy *towards* us (which would be counterintuitive since the universe is undergoing accelerated *expansion*)? I know that gravity will already yield an acceleration in our direction, but I'm asking if cosmic expansion will contribute an acceleration in the same direction, regardless of how small the effect may be. If true, do we have observational evidence for such an effect?

For those who are confused by the comments: this question once contained off-topic material, which led to the question being closed. I have removed them in the hope that the question can be reopened.

Comment: Concerning your idea of the Universe as a perpetual motion machine, note that [energy in not conserved in GR](https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2010/02/22/energy-is-not-conserved/).  So it's not altogether surprising that one could come up with a way to extract energy from cosmic expansion via some non-local process. (I'm reserving judgment as to whether this particular process would actually work.)

Comment: This post is picking and choosing when to account for relativity. How can the planets be far enough apart for Hubble expansion to affect the spaceship but also close enough together that the stick succeeds in making their relative velocity zero?

Comment: @ConnorBehan There is no contradiction with this. Imagine that, in the comoving frame of $A$, $B$ is moving towards us with velocity $HR$. Then we can use a stick to hold $A$ and $B$ together, and the stick experiences no stress at all. Note that Hubble expansion does not exert a repulsion force between two arbitrary objects, but rather, it only exerts such repulsion force when they have positive peculiar velocity relative to each other, and it becomes *attractive* when their peculiar velocity is negative. So, even if I remove the stick, $A$ and $B$ will not fly away from each other

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes, so the problem is why do people still keep saying that perpetual motion machines are always impossible, without excluding the circumstances where the energy is known to be not conserved. Is there a deeper theorem that proves that perpetual motion machines are indeed impossible even in GR?

Comment: We don't check personal theories on Physics SE.  Just glancing at your post you mix concepts from GR and Newtonian physics which is always a bad idea and m ore fundamentally as we do not know what dark matter (or dark energy) are any attempt to use them in this way is folly.

Comment: @StephenG Even if we are not sure what dark energy is, it is still a non-trivial problem if any mainstream theory on dark energy (e.g. cosmological constant) seems to support perpetual motion. In this case we do not prove the possibility of perpetual motion, but at least we cast doubt on that particular dark energy theory. Besides, it's true that I'm using Newtonian expressions of kinetic energy and gravity, but it's not hard to see that the errors are negligible. I'll edit the question to reflect this fact

Comment: @StephenG Besides, this is not a personal theory, but a question about if a well-established theory (Lambda-CDM) and a well-established conclusion (the non-existence of perpetual motion machines) are compatible. The bulk of the question is an attempt to prove that they are not compatible, and I'm asking if this proof is sound. If not, apart from the flaw of my proof, I'd also like to know if there is a proof that they are compatible.

Comment: Im trying to remember which famous figure once ended a letter with: “PS: If I would have had more time, I wouldve written a shorter letter.” Can’t help feel like you skipped some edits to get the core ideas out succinctly. Im sometimes guilty of same. If something is unnecessary to the concept it should be left out. Id also suggest moving most caveats and notes to the end. Just my two cents. About 90% of it is assessing or justifying or discussing it (all of point 8 just eg)

Comment: @AlBrown I sort of agree, and that's why the notes at the end of the question are already so long. But many people sneer and turn away at the very appearance of the phrase "perpetual motion", or if they discovered an undeclared approximation (for example the use of Newtonian physics), so I have to put some of the caveats in the main body just to keep them reading. And, point 8 was introduced to specifically suppress the comment that "the proposal seems sound but is completely  impractical, so we don't need to worry about it".

Comment: You specifically ask us to check your work and that's specifically against the rules here.  Whether it's an interesting topic or not is irrelevant.  That's my view on your question.  This would be more appropriate to a chat room IMO.

Comment: You've attempted to save this by choosing planets that were once hurtling towards each other and are therefore at rest with respect to each other now. But if that's the case, a ship travelling between them won't receive a kick. Also, dark energy (accelerating expansion, which actually doesn't appear to be needed in your protocol, just expansion) will make $H$ increase so that A and B eventually move apart again. Finally, you don't need energy conservation to object to perpetual motion machines, just the second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: @ConnorBehan No, I'm talking about the distant future, where $H$ is constant. At least in the cosmological constant model, in the distant future where dark energy dominates, dark energy is [proportional to the square of $H$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant), not the time derivative of $H$. And if you agree that a ship leaving a planet will receive a kick, then a ship traveling from $A$ to $B$ will also receive a kick, because whether or not it receives a kick relative to $A$ is independent of the presence of planet $B$, let alone the velocity of planet $B$

Comment: A cosmological model where objects following geodesics have a distance between them which asymptotes to a linear function of time? I don't think I've seen that. But it would strike down by objections other than the second law.

Comment: @StephenG Sorry, I didn't know this aspect about the rules. I have rephrased the question; it now asks whether this *kind* of perpetual motion machines is impossible. And if the answer is yes, I'm no longer requiring the answerer to point out where the error is. If an answer proves that such perpetual motion machines are impossible, by posting a general theorem rather than finding a mistake in my design, I'm still willing to accept the answer.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Constancy of $H$ implies that the distance grows exponentially, not linearly, with respect to time. It however implies that the recessional velocity grows linearly with respect to the distance, by the very definition of $H$. And I'm only using the latter fact. Time dependence is not explicitly used in the derivation at all.

Comment: If distances grow exponentially then A and B are going to fly apart no matter how much initial velocity one had towards the other.

Comment: @ConnorBehan I mean the distance of objects that have zero relative comoving/peculiar velocity, not an arbitrary pair of objects. I supposed that your previous comment also relied on this as a premise, so I did not repeat it. Distances of objects that have zero relative recessional velocity will remain at the same value, because when $H$ is constant, the acceleration due to $H$ is proportional to the recessional velocity, so when there is no recessional velocity there is no acceleration. This contrasts with e.g. gravity which gives nonzero acceleration even with zero velocity.

Comment: The relation $v(t) = Hx(t) - v_0$ doesn't look like something that could possibly hold for all times. It is just a $t \ll H^{-1}$ approximation to the derivative of $x(t) = x(0) e^{Ht} - v_0 t$.

Comment: @ConnorBehan No, $x(t)=x(0)e^{Ht}-v_0t$ cannot possibly be correct, because when $x(0)=0$ but $v_0\neq 0$, the spaceship will still eventually accelerate. The total velocity is the sum of the recessional velocity and the peculiar velocity, and the latter does not change as a result of cosmic expansion, otherwise this would mean that the comoving frame of the spaceship is not inertial.

Comment: Moderators - I deleted the bulk of the question so that it does not contain any "personal theory" anymore, which I suppose has addressed the cause that led to my question being closed. Please kindly consider reopening it, thanks! If the question still does not fit the criteria of this site, please kindly tell me how to edit the question further  so that it does.